# React Meteor, reactive prop and inner state

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor, draftjs

I have a component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js'
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg'
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css'
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html'

import toolbarOptions from './JpuriTextEditorOptions'

export default class TextEditor extends Component {
  state = {
    editorState: this.props.editorState
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    console.warn('componentWillReceiveProps')
    console.log('nextProps.editorState', nextProps.editorState)
    console.log('this.props.editorState', this.props.editorState)

    this.setState({editorState: nextProps.editorState})
  }

  onEditorStateChange = editorState => this.setState({editorState})

  onBlur = () => this.props.onBlur({key: this.props.myKey, value: draftToHtml(convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()))})

  render () {
    return (
      <Editor
        wrapperClassName={this.props.wrapperClassName}
        editorClassName={this.props.editorClassName}
        toolbarClassName={`toolbarAbsoluteTop ${this.props.toolbarClassName}`}

        wrapperStyle={this.props.wrapperStyle}
        editorStyle={this.props.editorStyle}
        toolbarStyle={this.props.toolbarStyle}

        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}

        toolbarOnFocus
        toolbar={toolbarOptions}

        onFocus={this.props.onFocus}
        onBlur={this.onBlur}
        onTab={this.props.onTab}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I pass to it a reactive prop, `this.props.editorState`
Then I set it inside the internal state to handle changes there. And only `onBlur` I save my changes to the mongo db.

Now there is a problem.
Whenever I click on the editor I see componentWillReceiveProps logs a few times. And it happens on every change thus I am not able to use my editor component properly. As it's cursor is being reset to the first letter with every click and change.

I am using this library of draftjs https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg

**EDIT**

More specifics for the question.
setting the state to this.props.editorState in the constructor or in the componentDidMount is solving the issue for the initial state. 
But there is still just one problem left.
In another component I have undo redo functionality that works directly with the db. Now if I type some text. Blur it my change is saved to the db and I can see the text because of the internal text. However if I click the undo button, the text will be undone from the db, however it will still be visible in the editor because of the internal state. So I will have to refresh to see my action undone.
With componentWillReceiveProps this issue is solved, however for some reason componentWillReceiveProps is being called every time the state changes even though the props are not changed. Thus bringing above mentioned issues.

Comment: if you are setting the state on each new prop received why do you use an internal state then?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **Controlled** pattern of this component then you should set the state internally and not set it from the outside via props.
For example, if you set the state on each new prop received then theres no reason to use an internal state.
According to their [DOCS](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs?_k=jjqinp) it seems like you are following their example of controlled `EditorState` except you are overriding your state on each new prop.
I think if you will just remove this behavior from `componentWillReceiveProps` 
i.e setting the state: `this.setState({editorState: nextProps.editorState})`
It should work like expected.

This is their example by the way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';


class ControlledEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    };
  }

  onEditorStateChange: Function = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
        editorClassName="demo-editor"
        onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
A followup to your comment, state initialization is usually made in the `constructor`.
But when you want to initialize state asynchronously you can't and should not do it in the constructor (nor in `componentWillMount`) because by the time the async operation will finish the `render` method will already be invoked.
The best place to do that is `componentDidMount` or eventHandlers, so in your case the `onBlur` eventHandler:
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';
    import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';

```
class ControlledEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    };
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  onBlur = (event) => {
    // do async stuff here and update state
  };

  render() {
    const { editorState } = this.state;
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
        editorClassName="demo-editor"
        onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
        onBlur={this.onBlur}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Sag1v my question is exactly about using external prop and internal state.
I use external prop from the db and give it to the initial state. Then as user starts typing, I do not want to save to the db while user is typing. So I save the changes to the db when the user finished typing i.e `onBlur`. And that is exactly when I need my state to be initialized with the external prop again.

Comment: But this way I just still have only internal state. What if user refreshes the browser? Wouldn't his typed text be lost?

Comment: on the `onBlur` handler you update stuff on the `db` (like my comment "do async stuff here and update state" )

Comment: Yes but I pass the saved state of the db via a prop, so I need somehow to set the state with that prop, otherwise it will always be empty.

Comment: Well you can do it in 2 places: 1. the `componentDidMount` for initial state from the server. 2. on the `onBlur` event handler inside the ajax callback after updating the server (though, you probably will have the same state as you are updating the server state from the UI so i see no point updating the UI again as its the same state).

Comment: yup that pretty much solves it, but I have just one more issue left.
Outside the editor component I have undo redo functionality. They work directly with the db. So if I click undo. My change in the db will be undone. However to see it in my component I will have to refresh it. This is my real problem, and that's why I tried using componentWillReceiveProps at first. What's your opinion on this?

Comment: you should use the same pattern for undo as well, you have an undo handler that go out to the DB, in the callback update the state same as you do with saving to the DB. with that said, i realy think you should consider a store manager (redux?) that will be easier to keep track on changes and reuse code. but this out of scope for this question :)

Comment: alright just one more question, to do so I need to move my state to a higher level component which is parent for both, no?
Yes I am going to migrate to redux soon, but for now migrating the whole project the redux is not possible because of time issues, you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153746/discussion-between-sag1v-and-hayk-safaryan).